# CSS import font link description

Tags: css

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu');
```

What is meant by `css?family=font-family` 
after the last `/`. I didn't understand what the code means. Can anyone describe them briefly

Comment: Read: https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started#specifying_font_families_and_styles_in_a_stylesheet_url

Answer (score 0):

that's a GET parameter to which the script can react

`css` will most likely lead to a file named index.php in the `css` directory, `?` indicates a GET parameter and `?family=Ubuntu'` indicates that the `familiy` GET parameter value is `Ubuntu`, which the php script will use to deliver the right font.

Answer (score 0):

It has no special meaning in CSS. It is just part of the URL.

The server will (probably using a server side programming language to dynamically generate some data using the values in the URL) serve up the requested stylesheet.